# How to translate this List to Java?

Tags: java, c#, list, arraylist, code-translation

I am currently getting an error requesting that certain identifiers are expected as I try to translate this C# code:

```
public static List<string> stopWords = new List<string> {"ON","OF","THE","AN","A" };
```

current faulty Java code:

```
public static List<String> stopWords = new ArrayList<String {"ON","OF","THE","AN","A" };
```

Comment: If you want to check if a word is a "stopWord", you'd likely be better off using a `Set`, because that'll perform better when calling `stopWords.contains(word)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
List<String> stopWords = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ON","OF","THE","AN","A" ));
```

Comment: You don't have to wrap the list in an `ArrayList` if the list won't be updated. Given the name `stopWords`, that is very likely here.

Comment: @Andreas based on the OPs (now deleted) comment, seemed he wanted to add to the list so removed the 2nd option....

Answer (score 2):

An alternative:

```
List<String> stopWords = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("ON");
    add("OF");
    add("THE");
    add("AN");
    add("A");
}};
```

Comment: nice trick, it is creating anonymous class which extends ArrayList, and it defines initialization block where adds all elements to list. it might not be a best answer, but it is definitelly nice trick

Comment: This is an abuse of anonymous inner classes - the accepted answer is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the words you want to put in a list to an array and add the array-elements using a for-loop:

```
  List<String> stopWords = new ArrayList<String>();
  String[] words = new String[] {
          "ON","OF","THE","AN","A"
  };
  for(String s : words) {
      stopWords.add(s);
  }
```